# How to display only as many pictures within a div as there is space for them?

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I have an empty div element like this:

```
<div class="mydiv"></div>
```

My product owner now wants to fill this div with pictures until there is no more space left (in vertical direction):

```
<div class="mydiv">
  <img src="pic1.jpg">
  <img src="pic2.jpg">
  <img src="pic3.jpg">
  <img src="pic4.jpg">
  <!-- keep going until mydiv is full -->
</div>
```

Unfortunately, the size of this div element is unknown until the page is actually loaded since it's a responsive website and thus the size of the div is dynamically adapted to the size of the screen/browserwindow. We do know the size of the images though.

Is there a pure HTML/CSS solution for this?

The only way I can think of is to check the width + height of the div during runtime via JavaScript and then do the math to see how many pictures are probably gonna fit in there and then insert only the images that will probably go in.

Comment: no there is no html/css pure solution.you need to use javascript

Comment: _until there is no more space left_......vertically/horizontally ?

Comment: @Jai Ah, sorry. Yeah I meant vertically.

Comment: you can use bootstrap css to get responsive images or take an idea from it.

Comment: Downvoter care to comment what's wrong with my question?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so there is a way to use it with "hacks" :

I made a first container that is the with you defined.

set `overflow:hidden` to this container

Then i made another container **inside** the first one but with greater width

Inside this container put all the images ( works vertically and horizontally, add `float:left` to my example to make it work horizontally )

[Here is the example](https://jsfiddle.net/1L99amvu/)

You see that i made 4 images ( faked them with fix position divs ) and that we can see 2.5 of them because of the container width.

Hope this trick is what you're looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution in javascript :

```
var mydiv = document.getElementById('mydiv') // or by class not important
while(!(mydiv .offsetHeight < mydiv .scrollHeight 
     || mydiv .offsetWidth < mydiv .scrollWidth)) {
    mydiv.innerHTML = mydiv.innerHTML + '<img src="myimg.jpg" />;
}
```